# Linux Mint 14 & Linksys AE1200 Wireless USB Not communicating

Tags: linux-mint, wireless-adapter

I am trying out Linux Mint 14. However, I am having difficulty getting wifi on my desktop. I cannot connect to the internet via LAN port due to the location of my router.

Any way I have tried some online forums to get some help with no luck. I installed the Win XP driver via ndiswrapper and it still is not communicating with Linux Mint. Any ideas or tutorials on how to get them to communicate?

Comment: Doesn't look linke Ndiswrapper says that it works with it, unfortunately Cisco doesn't really care about Linux support for their chipsets.  Refer to this very recent question on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100090/how-do-i-install-the-driver-for-my-linksys-ae1200-wireless-n-usb-adapter) (Since Linux Mint is a derivative of Ubuntu, it is still valid).

Comment: Note that the [second answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/203339/93215) on the thread @nerdwaller refers to suggests that they were able to get it to work using a different driver